# Scala: Pass plusMonth/plusYear functions as a parameter

Tags: function, scala, date, arguments

`plusMonths`/`plusYears` are functions of class LocalDate. Based upon what I want from my 'checkEOM' function, I want to pass them as a parameter. My function looks like this:

```
  protected def checkEOM(oldDate:LocalDate, stepFunc:(LocalDate) =>LocalDate, step:Int, forward:Boolean):LocalDate = {
      val newDate = oldDate.stepFunc(if (forward) step else -step)
      val yearNew = newDate.getYear
      val monthNew = newDate.getMonthValue
      if (oldDate.getDayOfMonth == getLastDayOfMonth(oldDate.getYear, oldDate.getMonthValue)) 
          LocalDate.of(yearNew, monthNew, getLastDayOfMonth(yearNew, monthNew))
      else
          newDate
}
```

It basically checks whether the given 'oldDate' is End of Month date. If it is, then in accordance with what function is passed in 'stepFunc' (i.e. plusMonths or plusYears), we get the 'newDate' or the EOM of newdate.How do I correctly pass them as parameters? I get the following error as of now:

```
value stepFunc is not a member of javax.time.LocalDate
```

Comment: I would consider simply using a (possibly negative) `Period` instead of separating it into an `Int`, a function and a `Boolean` , unless you expect using step functions more unusual than `plusMonths` or `plusYears`. (Although of course a negative `step` with false `forward` can be a lot of fun.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of things:

1. Since `plusMonths`, etc, take a long parameter, the type of `stepFunc` should be `stepFunc:(LocalDate, Long) => LocalDate`
2. To call step func, you can't use the method invocation syntax, since `stepFunc` isn't a method on `LocalDate`, but is instead a function. Instead use `stepFunc(oldDate, if (forward) num else -num)`
3. When you call `checkEOM`, make sure you pass in `plusMonths`, etc as an anonymous function of the correct type. E.g. `checkEOM(oldDate, _.plusMonths(_), ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. This is the correct implementation:

```
 protected def checkEOM(oldDate:LocalDate, stepFunc:(Int =>LocalDate), step:Int, forward:Boolean):LocalDate = {
  val newDate = stepFunc(if (forward) step else -step)
  val yearNew = newDate.getYear
  val monthNew = newDate.getMonthValue
  if (oldDate.getDayOfMonth == getLastDayOfMonth(oldDate.getYear, oldDate.getMonthValue)) 
LocalDate.of(yearNew, monthNew, getLastDayOfMonth(yearNew, monthNew))
   else
    newDate
}
```

And this would be the right way to call:

```
checkEOM(date, date.plusMonths(_), num, forward, holidays)
```

Since plusDays() has been implemented in Java and is not a static function, we need to make an object of it, then pass it as a partially applied function. Classic Scala!

Comment: In your version it's possible to use two different dates by mistake in the call to `checkEOM`. It would be safer and more DRY to follow kong's suggestion.